# Mouse clicks not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Lenovo Thinkpad P50s. Very quickly my mouse clicks stopped working. I can still click on the application launcher, but nowhere else. I’m totally new to Linux, so I have no idea how to start trying to fix this.

Update:
Now my red dot isn’t working, and I can only move the move the mouse with the touchpad.

Update 2:
Tried the `unity --replace &` solution and it did not work
I plugged in a wired mouse that works
When I do `cat /proc/bus/input/devices/` the touchpad is not listed at all.
I might add that the touchpad and trackpoint worked fine during the installation process.
Could this be a hardware issue? I didn't think so at first because the computer has just been sitting here on my couch the whole time.

Update 3:
Booted from the USB again and chose to try Ubuntu without installing and the mouse and touchpad work perfectly.

Going to try my luck reinstalling Ubuntu now

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have this same issue. I installed Ubuntu on an ASUS Zenbook, everything worked fine for a couple weeks. Then the trackpad and keyboard just stopped working. I can click on app icons to launch them, but once a window is open I can't click on anything or type.

Answer (score 9):

Try running this command in the terminal.

```
unity --replace &
```

If you're using the Compiz or Metacity window managers (which you are likely not, but if you're in this situation it will help), do this instead.

```
compiz --replace &
```

And for Metacity

```
metacity --replace &
```

It's *very* important you leave the `&` in there, so that the command is run in the background. If you CTRL-C or abort these commands while they're running, they could mess up your IO devices even more (for the session at least).

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/72112/mouse-clicks-suddenly-stopped-working-in-ubuntu) on Superuser might help you. The original poster actually had a hardware problem, but there are a lot of answers that might work for you.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. when I run `cat /proc/bus/input/devices/` I do not see the Synaptics touchpad listed at all

Comment: There's a touchpad disable button or key combo on some laptops.

Answer (score 3):

I had tried everthing, and the problem still wouldn't go away until I finally found [Mouse suddenly stops working in Ubuntu (running as guest in VirtualBox with Windows host)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196175/mouse-suddenly-stops-working-in-ubuntu-running-as-guest-in-virtualbox-with-wind)

```
ps -ax | grep VBoxClient
```

resulting e.g. in (among other entries):

```
1429 ?        Sl      0:00 /usr/bin/VBoxClient --draganddrop
```

Then kill all processes with

```
VBoxClient --draganddrop
```

After killing the processes, my mouse left click worked again. No need to reboot the VM every time!!

Comment: Saved my day! Did not even have right click.

Answer (score 1):

Just Open the Terminal using Ctrl+ALt+T and type the following commands 
**modprobe -r psmouse** Removes it 
**modprobe psmouse** readds it

Comment: This is unlikely to help as mouse movements are reported to work.

Comment: alright , yes it is working was an issue for some time

Comment: This one worked for me. thx

Answer (score 0):

Running 16.04 on a Dell 5520 and 13 months after buying the laptop (factory installed Ubuntu) I had this issue. Tried the "unity --replace &" command, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used `htop` command and killed (using the opiton `9`) one occurrence of `compiz`. It worked. But is it recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that if I **uncheck** the USB Logitech USB Receiver in the VM settings menu mouse pointer reappears.

Answer (score 0):

I have the mouse buttons suddenly stop responding (scroll also) in VirtualBox. This is rare, but a big hassle when it happens.

My solution so far has been to get back to Ubuntu, the host with <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> in the guest then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to host. Mouse buttons still dead.

Then using keyboard navigation, go to the VirtualBox management window and save/close the VM. Once the VM is not running, the mouse functions fully again. Killing the VM from Ubuntu using `kill -9`, or `top` will also restore the mouse but with loss/damage to the VM.